# Facebook application unable to pull email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Folks,

I have made several attempts but I am unable to figure out why I keep getting nil for email address. Here is what I am doing -

1) I created an application that asks for all the right extended permissions i.e. email, manage_pages etc that we need for our app.
2) User approves it and I make a Post Authorization call to my application, which sends me the fb user id.
3) I use the fb user id to FQL query 'select name, uid, email from users' and I get everything except for email which is always nil.

Any ideas what I am missing? Do I need to get some special approval from FB for the app or is there something else?

Please help - I have already spent days on this problem.

Thx
Rajat

Comment: Are you using the correct access token? i.e., the one provided by the permission challenge?

Answer (score 1):

Your `init_fb_connect` should look something  like this, so the you can get email address too:

```
<%= init_fb_connect "XFBML", {:app_settings => " { permsToRequestOnConnect : 'email' }" }%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Facebook does **not** return email addresses.  Checkout [this post on the FB developer's forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=51525)

It will return you a email hash, which you can use to match against emails that you might have in your system.

But for privacy reasons they will not give you email address that you do not already have.

Comment: According to this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user, if you ask for email extended permission, you should be able to fetch email address.

Is this not true?

This was launched somewhere around April.